# How to use useEffect with dependency when focusing the screen only in react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I want use useEffect with dependancy when the screen is focus in this screen.

useEffect will keep listening when screen is focused, it will do something if the dependancyVar change.    How can i do that?

```
 useFocusEffect(
         useEffect(()=>{
           if(dependancyVar){
              //do something
           }
           else{
              //do other things
           }
           return()=>{
             alert("Screen was unfocused")
           }
         },[dependancyVar])
     );
```

the code below is work for me but I don't know should I use `useFocusEffect`

```
const isFocused= useIsFocused();
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(isFocused){
      if(dependencyVar){
        //do something
      }
      else{
        //do other things
      }
    }
  },[isFocused, dependencyVar])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React navigation suggest using useCallback within useFocusEffect instead of useEffect.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

```js
useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    let isActive = true;

    const fetchUser = async () => {
      try {
        const user = await API.fetch({ userId });

        if (isActive) {
          setUser(user);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // Handle error
      }
    };

    fetchUser();

    return () => {
      isActive = false;
    };
  }, [userId])
);
```

Comment: finally , it work for me .
```
useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
      if(dependencyVar){
        alert("a = true")
      }
      else{
        alert("a = false")
      }
  }, [dependencyVar])
);

```